# Azure Data Factory REST API cannot pass parameters

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory

I'm writing a simple PowerShell script responsible for triggering ADF pipeline execution.
I'm using the following snippet:

```
    $callUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$($Config.subId)/resourceGroups/$($config.azRg)/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/$($config.factoryName)/pipelines/$pipeName/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01"
Write-Host $callUri
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $AccessToken" 
    Content       = 'application/json'
}

$body = "{""param1"":""abc""}"



$ret = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $callUri -Headers $headers -Body $pipeParams
return  $ret
```

}

The problem I'm facing at the moment is that the pipeline is executed correctly on the Azure end, however, my parameter values are not being included.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code which is working for me.

```
$callUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<Resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<Data Factory name>/pipelines/<pipeline name>/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01"

$AccessToken = "<Access token>"
$body=@{"param1"="abc"
}| ConvertTo-Json

$headers = @{
'Authorization' = "Bearer $AccessToken"
'content_type' = "application/json"
}

$ret = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $callUri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
return  $ret
```

Here my parameter name is `param1` and I am passing value `abc`.

[image]

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! Btw I'm a bit surprised how ADF Rest API reports issues with API calls (i.e. no warnings returned to the client side when body is malformed...)

Comment: I think it is taking the whole string as a parameter and assuming that it's a new parameter. And for the `param1` parameter, it is taking the value from the default value which is null. This might be a reason for it but not sure about it though.